# Android data synchronization from device sqlite to server

Tags: android, sqlite, data-synchronization

In my application, I have two data management sources, one through web services and another standby in SQLite database in the device itself. In this, I want to add the feature to transfer the data from the device to server and from server to device if the web services available. Please suggest what would be the best way to perform this implementation.

Answer (score 4):

[Virgil Dobjanschi](https://twitter.com/#!/vdobjanschi), author of the official Twitter app for Android, describes designing such data handling in [his Google I/O 2010 presentation on Android REST client applications](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE).